# When PHP runs a module, Apache cannot start

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Yesterday, I was enjoying just messing around with the website code, since I've not touched the actual settings of PHP and Apache since yesterday... (I must say I had the module php_mysql enabled) I made a MySQL connector yesterday and worked perfectly! This morning, I start up the computer and when I try to run Apache, it gives me 'The requested operation has failed'. I look in the apache log and I see this.

```
[Fri Feb 22 08:07:39 2013] [warn] pid file C:/dev/progs/Apache/Apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

I looked around the internet and found I must delete that file. I tried deleting then restarting but that didn't work.

Then I found that disabling all PHP modules will work. So I went ahead and disabled the php_mysql module (that is the only one enabled).

Then it starts up again! Except I want it to start with MySQL. Then I try to run the connector on my php page. I get this.

```
[22-Feb-2013 07:59:54] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\dev\www\test\index.php on line 48
```

So I really want mysql to run on PHP, but I don't want mysql to stop me running Apache...

Any help?

(Running Apache/2.0.64 PHP/5.2.17 MySQL5.6 - Win32 Home Premium)

Comment: The PID file warning is not the real error - it's just information. What about if you disable the mysql one and enable the mysqli module? Is it the same error?

Comment: I've tried the mysqli approach. Still no luck. It seems that I am unable to use modules.

Comment: No, it is impossible that you are unable to use modules. You must have some other errors in your error.log file, or errors on PHP startup. Either your modules are not at the version required, or they are not in the right place.

Comment: They are in the correct place, it's just I am unable to start the Apache. I've run Test Configuration executable and it says the httpd.conf is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the php.ini and copied it again and re-configured it. Working now!